# Terraform is not destroying Frontdoor resources in the correct order. How can I fix this?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-front-door

I have recently been building Frontdoor in Terraform, it's been quite a challenge. I have managed to build it but now I need to destroy it and the issue becomes is for some reason Terraform will try to destroy the front door instance before it destroys the DNS record, which really defeats the object of trying to build all this in Terraform for us.

This is because I was originally using the portal and the same error comes up.

> Front Door Name: "testingfrontdoor"): performing Delete:
> frontdoors.FrontDoorsClient#Delete: Failure sending request:
> StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an
> error. Status= Code="Conflict" Message="Cannot delete frontend
> endpoint "portal-staging.jason.website" because it is still directly
> or indirectly (using "afdverify" prefix) CNAMEd to front door
> "testingfrontdoor.azurefd.net". Please remove the DNS CNAME records
> and try again."

If you try to delete the front door instance before deleting the DNS CNAME because by design Frontdoor does a lookup to see if the DNS record still exists, it will fail to delete.

How do I tell terraform to first delete the DNS record with Cloudflare before deleting Frontdoor?

Please see my code below:

```html
resource "azurerm_frontdoor" "jccroutingrule" {
  depends_on = [
    cloudflare_record.create_frontdoor_CNAME,
    azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault,
    azurerm_key_vault_certificate.jcimportedcert
  ]
  name                = "testingfrontdoor"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.Terraform.name
  #enforce_backend_pools_certificate_name_check = false
  routing_rule {
    name               = "jccroutingrule"
    accepted_protocols = ["Http", "Https"]
    patterns_to_match  = ["/*"]
    frontend_endpoints = ["jccfrontendendpoint","${local.frontendendpoint2}"]
    forwarding_configuration {
      forwarding_protocol = "MatchRequest"
      backend_pool_name   = "jccbackendpool"
    }
  }

  backend_pool_load_balancing {
    name                        = "jccloadbalancesettings"
    sample_size                 = 255
    successful_samples_required = 1
  }

  backend_pool_health_probe {
    name                = "jcchealthprobesettings"
    path                = "/health/probe"
    protocol            = "Https"
    interval_in_seconds = 240
}


  backend_pool {
    name = "jccbackendpool"
    backend {
      host_header = format("portal-staging-westeurope.jason.website")
      address     = format("portal-staging-westeurope.jason.website")
      http_port   = 80
      https_port  = 443
      weight      = 50
      priority    = 1
      enabled     = true
    }

    load_balancing_name = "jccloadbalancesettings"
    health_probe_name   = "jcchealthprobesettings"
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = "jccfrontendendpoint"
    host_name = format("testingfrontdoor.azurefd.net")
  }

  frontend_endpoint {
    name      = local.frontendendpoint2
    host_name = format("portal-staging.jason.website")
  }

}

resource "azurerm_frontdoor_custom_https_configuration" "portal_staging_https_config" {
  frontend_endpoint_id              = "${azurerm_frontdoor.jccroutingrule.id}/frontendEndpoints/${local.frontendendpoint2}"
  custom_https_provisioning_enabled = true

  custom_https_configuration {
    certificate_source                      = "AzureKeyVault"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_secret_name = "imported-cert"
    azure_key_vault_certificate_vault_id    = azurerm_key_vault.jctestingenv_keyvault.id
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `depends_on`?

Comment: What version of terraform and what version of the azure provider are you using? If your not using the latest, upgrade. Providing this has all been created using terraform, terraform should destroy it correctly. If not I'd raise a [bug in on the Azure RM](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm)

Comment: @Marcin yes you can see in my code that there is a Depends On Statement here: `cloudflare_record.create_frontdoor_CNAME`

Comment: @liam I'm using terraform Version 1.1.4 sorry what is azuread got to do with frontdoor?

Comment: Azure ad was a typo. Your first step (pretty much everytime something doesnt work) is to upgrade both terraform and the azure rm to the latest version. The api's, terraform, etc. are all fast moving. If you don't keep it up to date then all bets are off

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug in Terraform and therefore there is no solution.

Comment: @Liam There's no reason to close it if it's a bug, just be sure the question and answer make it clear what version it applies to, what the symptoms are, and what the workaround or resolution is (even if it's upgrading to a specific fix).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a known issues, discussed [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11231).

Workaround is to disable the check:

```
az feature register --namespace Microsoft.Network --name BypassCnameCheckForCustomDomainDeletion
```

Comment: I know thats a work around but it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Looks like this was [fixed in 2.60.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11715#issuecomment-845582438)?

Comment: Well if it's a bug @Jason what do you expect us to do?

Comment: @Jason you mean the workaround does not work for you or you dont want to use it as it is not a proper solution?

Comment: Its not really a solution, I have created the DNS record using Terraform, and I have created Frontdoor using Terraform, now as I understand the problem. Frontdoor will do a DNS check on the record, before deletion. Now my expectation was, being that there is DependOn on the DNS record Terraform should delete the record first allowing frontdoor to delete

Comment: Well you need to raise that with Terraform. I'm not clear what your expecting as an "answer" here?

Comment: It is somewhat of a catch-22 between Terraform trying to delete in proper order (reversed compared to its creation) and Azure trying to protect you from dangling DNS records. There is no solution for this right now. The new Front Door Standard/Premium provider might work better but that is still work in progress

Comment: But if I have put a Dependson, on a resource with terraform surely on a destroy Terraform should delete that resource first no? Thats basically what I am asking?

Comment: Yes it should, but if that's not technically possible then it can't. It seems MS moved the goal posts unexpectedly, that happens with Terraform. Upgrade, if that doesn't work, raise a bug on Github

Comment: Ohh okay I understand a bit more now why. I was putting it down as if Terraform behaves this way then technically that should get me round this problem. Thanks

Comment: depends_on means: your DNS record needs to exist first before AFD gets created. That works. On destroy however, Terraform will work the other way round: It will delete the dependent resource (AFD) first, then the other resource (CNAME). But this is being prevented by Azure. So Terraform cannot do its thing. It is not a bug in TF.